# j2me JAR Manifest, JAD File and Nokia Publish QA failure

Tags: java, java-me, jar, nokia-s40, jad

Recently I've developed some application which is simple Weider 6 excersises browser.

I've created manually JAD file with elements from JAR manifest, however my application was revoked by Nokia Publish QA team with following reason:

```
Dear publisher,
While processing your content we found the following MIDlet-attributes are not present in the JAD and JAR manifest files:

Key 'MicroEdition-Profile' is not in the .jad and .jar.
Key 'MicroEdition-Configuration' is not in the .jad and .jar.
Key 'MIDlet-1' is not in the .jad and .jar.
Key 'MIDlet-Name' is not in the .jad and .jar.
Key 'MIDlet-Version' is not in the .jad and .jar.
Key 'MIDlet-Vendor' is not in the .jad and .jar.
```

What is really weird because my manifest looks like following:

```
MIDlet-Version: 1.0.0
MIDlet-Vendor: Michal Kulesza
MIDlet-Jar-URL: Weider6.jar
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.0
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.1
MIDlet-1: Weider6,/1.png,me.kulesza.WeiderExcercises
MIDlet-Name: Weider6
```

and JAD file is almost the same:

```
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 199784
Sealed: true
MIDlet-Version: 1.0.0
MIDlet-Vendor: Michal Kulesza
MIDlet-Jar-URL: Weider6.jar
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.0
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.1
MIDlet-1: Weider6,/1.png,me.kulesza.WeiderExcercises
MIDlet-Name: Weider6
```

Did anyone of you experienced such issue?
Am I doing anything wrong or it's their fault?

Answer (score -1):

You can check the JAD File online with my JAD-Checker
[jadcheck.appspot.com](http://jadcheck.appspot.com/)

You should probably also include these entries:
MIDlet-Icon
MIDlet-Description
But these missing entries can not be the reason for the error report you got.

To me it looks like something went wrong during uploading. For example, an error you can easy do: select the file to upload, but not confirm it to start the actual upload.
It happen to me that when I finally saved the whole form, the files were not uploaded, the system used my old files, and the QA has reexamined my old version.
Now before I submit to QA, I always download what I have uploaded, to check that the system has really my new files.

There is an extra "verify" button. It should catch errors like this one.